# "I am John(,) from the USA" — Is the comma necessary?

Tags: relative-clauses, commas, restrictive-clauses, non-restrictive

When restrictive phrases are used to modify the noun, the speaker implies there is more than just one of that thing.
If there is only one, then a comma is needed so it is non-restrictive.

But I often hear people use restrictive phrases to modify their names or homes. People only have one name and one home, so why don't they use non-restrive phrases?

**Example 1**

> The amusement park is not far away from **my home in LA**.

**Example 2**

> The amusement park is not far away from **my home, in LA**.

People say Example 1 more than Example 2.

**Example 3**

> I am **John from the USA.**

**Example 4**

> I am **John, from the USA.**

People say Example 3 more than Example 4.

Comment: There is no restrictive phrase. That said, from my home in LA has  one meaning and no comma goes there. **However**, if you are writing a dialogue for a script, you might (repeat might) do Ex. 4.

Comment: If people are 'saying' these sentences, you don't know whether they intend a comma or not!

Comment: "I am John, [and I come] from the USA" as opposed to "You have met John from Scotland - I'm John from the USA" (using the phrase as a distinguishing label).

Comment: And note that in your amusement park example "away" sounds the most awkward part of those sentences.

Comment: People don't "say" comma, they use that punctuation mark for *writing*. (one comma)  Speaker: *"The amusement park is not far from where I live."* (no commas). If the amusement park is in the city/district where the listener also lives, adding the city's name is redundant.

Comment: I disagree with @Lambie. Your example 2 can be correct if the amusement park is in LA and the writer lives near it but not in LA. Example 1 can be correct if the writer has several residences and means to specify which one is being discussed.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum Yes, in speaking all of them are fine (dialogue) but not **in a written text**.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, but different. The choice depends on whether the speaker is using the secondary piece of information to (i) identify themselves, or (ii) as additional, optional information.

For example, if you were introducing yourself to somebody for the first time, you may give them various pieces of information about themselves, including your name:

> I'm John, aged 39, I'm married and from the USA.

The use of commas is normal to separate what are essentially list items.

However, consider this example - you know two people with the name 'John' and want to refer to one of them in conversation. You could add this piece of information to identify them:

> My friend John from the USA is coming to visit me.

No comma is used because "John from the USA" is acting as a unit of speech to uniquely identify the person you mean.

It wouldn't be unusual for a person to identify themselves in this way, either:

> Hi, this is Colin from Accounts.